# CSS Library for Mobile Web Apps

Tags: css, mobile

I was wondering if anybody knows of any css resources that are geared strictly towards mobile web apps?

I am building a mobile app using backbone and zepto, but am missing a framework for handling the main user interface components.

I know there is jQuery mobile and ST2 (and yes I know you can just grab their css), but I was wondering if there are any resources that are standalone mobile css libraries and focus on using css transitions to mimic device behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[topcoat.io](http://topcoat.io/) is still in an early stage, but is developing quite fast.
For simple example application have a look at: [Sample Mobile / PhoneGap Application with Backbone.js and Topcoat](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/sample-mobile-phonegap-application-with-backbone-js-and-topcoat/)

Question is a bit older, but I just stumbled across it. Maybe this is useful for someone :)

Comment: This wasn't around when I was looking for something of this nature, but yours is the closest answer to what I was looking for. Also check out ratchet, that is what I really wanted at the time: http://maker.github.io/ratchet/

Comment: oh nice. but it's a prototyping tool only, right? just checked the issues on github where people talking about that.

Comment: If you're looking for a JavaScript MVC as well, have a look at [ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com). They combine [topcoat.io](http://topcoat.io) with [angularjs](http://angularjs.org). They provide CSS animations ootb as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any css frameworks that are strictly mobile but these ones are very good and have media queries that help make their stuff look good on mobile devices. Bootstrap is highly modular so it is a great starting point:

bootstrap - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

foundation - http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: Bootstrap is awesome, but I was hoping for a library that focuses mainly on css transitions to recreate the animations that one experiences on a native app. Something like bootstrap (where you basically just drop in classes and format your markup a certain way) but that recreates a native mobile experience with css3 transitions and mock phone chrome would be insane.

Comment: Pure css? What are you looking for exactly? You are going to need a combination of JS and CSS to do transitions page/menu transitions properly.

Comment: Its a long time since I posted this, but this is exactly what I was looking for: http://maker.github.com/ratchet/

Answer (score 0):

There's now Kendo Mobile available that does this, but it's not free or that cheap though.
http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx